# I am unable to preview any game play in blender

Tags: game-engine

I have a simple FPS setup, but pressing p to play will not do anything. Is there any information available for this kind of problem? I set as blender game, and it will not do anything but animations. The file came from blender artist thing.  if you can tell me how I can put the file here, so someone else can try it and see if there is something I am doing wrong.

I posted the link to the file I am having trouble with.  It is from 2006 apparently, so maybe it is from an older version of blender.  however if anyone can get it to work I learn much easier by seeing something in action than trying to follow fast talking tutorials on youtube.

As I am Aware now that this can be fixed using an older version, I think it should be amended to work in the current version, so myself and others are not frustrated learning to use blender.  I am not familiar yet enough to fix it, but I think it might be looked at as a tutorial file.

Comment: If the file is already hosted on blender artists, then all that's needed is the link to the BA post. If not, you could upload it via [blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/).

Comment: http://blenderartists.org/forum/search.php?searchid=2955782   this is the link to the file.. I am using the top link on that page of files.

Comment: @Bryan That link goes to some search results.. Assuming you mean the top result, then it looks like a pretty old file, most likely for 2.4x. Not sure I have the right post though, as the download link in the top post goes to a 404.

Comment: @Bryan Never mind, I found the right link. It is a 2.4x file, however the engine is set to *Blender Internal*. Recently it was made so the game engine can only be started while in *Blender Game*, so change the drop down where it says "Blender Render" (at the top of the screen) to *Blender Game*. Then press P. The game engine starts, however none of the python will work as the API was changed between 2.4 and 2.7. If you like, you can find blender 2.49b [here](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.49b/), which runs it as expected.

Comment: So is there a way to correct the problems in the current version?  say going back through python and readjusting the code for the current version?  This looked like a great starter to learn to program FPS games in blender and others may be able to use it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The engine is set to *Blender internal*. [As of 2.73](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/UI#Small_Improvements) <kbd>P</kbd> only starts the game engine when the render engine is set to *Blender Game* at the top of the screen:

[image]

Also note that that file was made in 2.4x. The 2.4x python api is not compatible with the 2.5x+ api, so the python scripts won't work. If you want to run that file, you can download 2.49b [here](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.49b/).